# Ring structure on a space of functions between vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, local-rings, germs, jet-bundles

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)) about jets, in the section about rigorous definitions, for the algebro-geometric definition, they take the vector space $C^\infty_p(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ of germs of smooth functions at $p$, and then consider the ideal $\mathfrak m_p$ of germs which vanish at $p$ (which they claim to be a maximal ideal of the local ring $C^\infty_p$), then take the quotient $C^\infty_p(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)/\mathfrak m_p^{k+1}$ and call that a $k$-th order jet space.

My question is: what is the ring structure on this space of germs? I don't see any obvious choice, since functions to $\mathbb R^m$ cannot be multiplied without introducing some additional structure.

Comment: On $\Bbb R^m$ you have a ring structure defined by $(x_1,..,x_m)\cdot (y_1,..,y_m) = (x_1 \cdot y_1, ..., x_m\cdot y_m)$ ie just multiply componentwise. Thats the structure used here.

Comment: @s.harp: So the ring structure depends on a choice of basis? If I wanted to do the same thing with arbitrary (finite dimensional) vector spaces, is there some canonical choice for a ring structure?

Comment: The ring structure depends on the basis - but the ideal $\mathfrak m$ and its powers do not.

Comment: @s.harp: Thanks, that clears it up!